# Is there a way to add a document to a Google Form so that end users can access it to answer questions?

Tags: google-forms

Is there a way to add a document to a Google Form so that end users can access it to answer questions within the survey?

Comment: I expect you can share a Google Document and use the link on the form. Are you looking for something more than that?

Answer (score 0):

- Google Forms has description fields for most of the elements. You could put there a link to your document.
- One alternative is to use a Section header to include in the description field the content of your document. Thi will work if it is plain text.
- Another alterternative is to also use the image sections to include images of your document.
- One more alternative is to embed your form and your document side by side on a web page. You could use Google Sites or another similar tool to do this.